# Is AWS S3 trigger is Sync or Async process?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm writing file into aws s3 for every 10 sec, S3 is triggering aws lambda function.

Every write is calling lambda function if function takes more then 10 sec to process the file, let's say 1 min. In this case, S3 will be waiting for the process.

But, S3 is triggering function when file writes into s3.

Here i need s3 trigger has to wait for response. What setting i need do ?

EX:

> 2019-06=27 07:34:20 -> file_1.txt -> process time 8 sec
>
> 2019-06=27 07:34:30 -> file_2.txt -> process time 60 sec
>
> 2019-06=27 07:34:40 -> file_3.txt -> process time 8 sec

Comment: They are async and might sometimes trigger multiple times for the same file.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-services.html

[image: Sync]

[image: Async]

From this S3 is a Async lambda invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

> Amazon S3 invokes your function asynchronously with an event that contains details about the object. The following example shows an event that Amazon S3 sent when a deployment package was uploaded to Amazon S3.